# Remove Everyone Permission From A Channel Discord.JS

Tags: permissions, discord.js, channel

I want to delete `SEND_MESSAGES` permission from `everyone` role with Discord.JS
Here is the code that I tried to use

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "test") {
    client.channels.cache.get("709070158416707656").client.guilds.cache.get(msg.guild.id).roles.find("name", "everyone").remove('SEND_MESSAGES: true')
  }
})
```

When i try to use that code, the bot response a error in console. The error is: `client.channels.cache.get(...).client.guilds.cache.get(...).roles.find is not a function`

How to fix the code??

Answer (score 0):

Okok i find how to fix the code.

```
let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone");

client.channels.cache.get("709070158416707656").overwritePermissions([
    {
        id: role.id,
        deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES"]
    }
]);
```